# Play 2.5.X dependency injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I am upgrading play framework app from 2.4.6 to 2.5.x.
There are several occurrences where I call helper methods which belongs to some object. These helper methods use play's built-in classes(for example play.api.Play.current.configuration.underlying.getString) to get the job done.

I get following warning: "**method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead**"

If I face this problem in class method then I can use dependency injection. How to deal with such a situation where method belongs to object and I am warned to use DI?

Comment: If you use dependency injection you can just change your object to class and it will do the work. Annotate it with @Singleton

Comment: Problem with this approach is if I want to use helper method(after changing object to class with @Singleton annotation), play gives following error:


object ClientHandler is not a member of package controllers
[error] Note: class ClientHandler exists, but it has no companion object.
[error]     controllers.ClientHandler.getClientUrl

Answer (score 2):

Play Framework usually provides a class you can inject instead of using the old static references.

For example, the below would mean you can stop using `Play.current.configuration` and `DB`:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.Database
import play.api.Configuration

class MyClass @Inject() (configuration: Configuration, db: Database) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I am using object not class.

Comment: That's the whole point. The singleton `object` is deprecated. The injected `Configuration` instance should behave identical to the singleton `object`. To use this, you should however change your own singleton `object`s to `class`' as well. Then you can inject the helper `class` into your controller (or where ever else you might need it)

Comment: Agreed, but if I change object to class with @Singleton annotation, play doesn't allow me to call helper method with className.helperMethod().

Comment: can you please provide some code? Because @colinjwebb 's solution works for me, and it's also the same what i suggested :) If you want to you can leave the Singleton annotation

Comment: I call method EMSUtils.notifyRegistration which will send HTTP request to EMS service.
Method notifyRegistration reads one configuration parameter from application.conf.

def confirmRegistration(customerEmail: String, code: UUID) = Action.async { implicit request =>
  Logger.debug(s"Received request: [${request.path}] for [${request.method}]")
  Future {
    Invitations.get(code, customerEmail).headOption.map { invitation =>
      Customer.add(invitation)
      val response = Await.result(EMSUtils.notifyRegistration(invitation), 5 seconds)
    }
    Ok()
  }
}